# Firestore takes 2 minutes to write a single document?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Why is this simple code snippet takes 2 minutes to complete ?

To reproduce, just replace `this.firestoreProvider` with `admin.initializeApp().firestore()`

```
  console.log('Init the cat')
        const kittyRef = this.firestoreProvider
            .fs
            .collection('cats')
            .doc('kitty')
        await kittyRef.set({
            name: 'Kitty',
            age: 85,
            feedCount: 0,
        })
        const now = Date.now()
        console.log('Feeding the cat',)
        await this.firestoreProvider.fs.runTransaction(async transaction => {
            const snapshot = await transaction.get(kittyRef);
            const cat = snapshot.data()
            if (cat.isDead) return
            if (cat.age > 84) {
                cat.isDead = true
                await kittyRef.set(cat); // this need be written to the db
                const lapse = Date.now() - now
                console.log(`Took ${lapse/1000} seconds`)
                throw new Error('Kitty is dead')
            }
            cat.feeCount++
            await transaction.set(kittyRef, cat)
        }, {maxAttempts: 5})
        console.log('success')
```

This prints

```
Init the cat
Feeding the cat
Took 121.001 seconds
(node:12924) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Kitty is dead
```

I checked on the firebase console, the document is written correctly BUT

**121 seconds** to write a single document ??

I also discovered that once you run this code, all client that tries to read the `kittyRef` are freezing for about 2 minutes ( Android Client is crashing after the 2 minutes! )

Comment: This question is different because the write action succeeds but takes 2 minutes.

Comment: Except for the timing code, the code and cause of the freeze/delay are exactly the same, the direct use of `kittyRef.set()` while inside a transaction that is dependent on a read to `kittyRef`